# Python3: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I'm following the Taboola documentation to the T in order to update a campaign with retargeting audience lists, but I get this error "string indices must be integers" and I don't know what is wrong. I searched through the site but I can't find find a question with JSON request formatted like mine below.

Thank you for your help,

```
data = {
    "collection:" [
        "type": "INCLUDE" ,
        "collection:" [
            23950,
            23951,
            23949,
            23954,
            23953
        ]
    ]
}



#Create campaign
resp = requests.post(url="https://backstage.taboola.com/backstage/api/1.0/" + accountName + "/campaigns/" + campId + "/targeting/audience_segments", data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

**Documentation** (PDF - see last page): 
https://github.com/taboola/Backstage-API/raw/master/Backstage%20API%20-%20Targeting.pdf

Comment: Possible typo: consider changing `"collection:"` to `"collection":`, and remember that dicts require curly brackets, not square.

Comment: Looks like the documentation has lots of typos like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not formatted correcting as per API requirements:

```
data = {
    "collection": {
        "type": "INCLUDE" ,
        "collection": [
            23950,
            23951,
            23949,
            23954,
            23953
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find find a question with JSON request formatted like mine

The problem isn't specific to how JSON is formatted; especially because the error is from Python interpreter, but not the `json` module.

It's how you typed it.

This is trying to index a string (which must be an integer)

```
"collection:" [...]
```

What you need instead looks like a key-value pair

```
"collection" : [...]
```